# Run JUnit from makefile (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError)

Tags: junit, makefile

I've got a JUnit project that I want to add in a Toolchain. This toolchain using Makefile.
The Makefile is not in my prject directory.
So I tryied to put a "test" rules in this makefile as following :

```
PROJPATH=TestJUnit/Test/

PACKAGE=com/project/package/name/

LIB=$(PROJPATH)lib/
SRC=$(PROJPATH)src/$(PACKAGE)
BIN=$(PROJPATH)bin/$(PACKAGE)

---------  All the acces to lib.jar and .class used during the test ------
CLASSPATH=.:$(LIB)junit.jar:$(LIB)opal-library.jar:$(SRC):$(BIN)

--------- Name of test in order of wanted excecution -------------  
JAVASRC=    Test1\
            Test2\
            Test3\

test:
        java -classpath $(JUNITPATH) org.junit.runner.JUnitCore $(JAVASRC)
```

When I try to launch 'make test'

I've got the following message:

```
JUnit version 4.11
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Test1 (wrong name: com/project/name/Test1)
```

I try everything possible even to launch the java command in my project directory but nothing work.
All the .class and .java are respectivly in the bin and src directorys.

Comment: I suspect that you have whitespace in your `JUNITPATH` variable. Try doing `JUNITPATH=junit.jar:dir1:dir2:...` instead.

Comment: Would `TESTPACKAGE` need to be in `JUNITPATH` for this to work? Or would you need to give java the full path to the `.java` files? (As opposed to the bare `Test1.java` names you are currently giving it?)

Comment: @JesperE all the path in the claxspath are already concat without Carriage return. I wrote it down like that here so everyone can clearly read them kind of.

Comment: @EtanReisner I had moove test package and SRC path in the JUNITPATH and still got the error

Comment: Can you run the tests by hand? What command line do you need to use to do that?

Comment: Impossible even in command line when i try a simple command in my project folder like this:

     java -cp ./lib/junit.jar:.:./src/com/package/name/:./bin/com/package/name/:./lib/opal-library-0d7b10e3a298-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore Test1

Comment: https://www.owsiak.org/you-need-no-maven-to-run-junit-tests/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok Guys I fond the problem.
It's seems that the class path was not bad but the way of calling the test was wrong.
By simply add the /src and /bin in the classpath (without the sub package directory) and concat the package name to the test class name the test are succesfully launched.

something like that:

```
PROJPATH=TestJUnit/Test/

PACKAGE=com.project.package.name.

LIB=$(PROJPATH)lib/
SRC=$(PROJPATH)src/
BIN=$(PROJPATH)bin/

---------  All the acces to lib.jar and .class used during the test ------
CLASSPATH=.:$(LIB)junit.jar:$(LIB)opal-library.jar:$(SRC):$(BIN)

--------- Name of test in order of wanted excecution -------------  
JAVASRC=    $(PACKAGE)Test1\
            $(PACKAGE)Test2\
            $(PACKAGE)Test3\

test:
        java -classpath $(JUNITPATH) org.junit.runner.JUnitCore $(JAVASRC)
```